# GWT/CSS - styling part of a label

Tags: javascript, css, html, gwt

Is there a way to style part of the text in a label - change color, boldness, size, etc?

Comment: Yes, but explain what do you mean by 'part' of the label. A particular word, or a property (color, font-weight, etc)..?

Comment: some of the text - only the third work, for example

Comment: Yes. Or maybe more precisely, characters 10 to 15

Comment: Find part of text you want to style with javascript, add `span` tag around it, and add some class to this span, and voila!

Comment: I don't think i understand - how can i do that in code?

Comment: @Erik You get better answers if you provide specific examples. 'part of the text' is a bit generic. Is it some static text? Is it user typed input? It matter for the solution. If you add some context and examples of what you are trying to do you will get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTML widget instead of Label. Then:

```
HTML label = new HTML();
label.setHtml("Brown <span class=\"brown\">fox</span>");
```

Answer (score -1):

I was a little bored, and I thought I might be able to offer something useful, so, that said, I offer *this*:

```
function elemStyle(el, needle, settings) {
    // if there's no 'el' or 'needle' arguments, we quit here
    if (!el || !needle) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // if 'el' has a nodeType of 1, then it's an element node, and we can use that,
        // otherwise we assume it's the id of an element, and search for that
        el = el.nodeType == 1 ? el : document.getElementById(el);

        // if we have a 'settings' argument and it's an object we use that,
        // otherwise we create, and use, an empty object
        settings = settings && typeof settings === 'object' ? settings : {};

        // defining the defaults
        var defaults = {
            'class': 'presentation',
            'elementType': 'span'
        },
            // get the text from the 'el':
            haystack = el.textContent || el.innerText;

        // iterate over the (non-prototypal) properties of the defaults
        for (var prop in defaults) {
            if (defaults.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                // if the 'settings' object has that property set
                // we use that, otherwise we assign the default value:
                settings[prop] = settings[prop] || defaults[prop];
            }
        }

        // defining the opening, and closing, tags (since we're using HTML
        // as a string:
        var open = '<' + settings.elementType + ' class="' + settings.class + '">',
            close = '</' + settings.elementType + '>';

        // if 'needle' is an array (which is also an object in JavaScript)
        // *and* it has a length of 2 (a start, and stop, point):    
        if (typeof needle === 'object' && needle.length === 2) {
            var start = needle[0],
                stop = needle[1];
            el.innerHTML = haystack.substring(0, start) + open + haystack.substring(start, stop) + close + haystack.substring(stop);
        }
        // otherwise if it's a string we use regular expressions:
        else if (typeof needle === 'string') {
            var reg = new RegExp('(' + needle + ')');
            el.innerHTML = haystack.replace(reg, open + '$1' + close);
        }
    }
}
```

The above is called like so:

```
// a node-reference, and a string:
elemStyle(document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0], 'Input');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VRnpc/).

```
// a node-reference, and a start-stop array:
elemStyle(document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0], [6, 8]);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VRnpc/1/).

```
// an id (as a string), and a string to find, with settings:
elemStyle('label1', 'Input', {
    'elementType' : 'em'
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VRnpc/3/).

This could definitely do with some error-catching (for example if an array is passed into the function that's less, or more, than two-elements [nothing happens](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VRnpc/4/), and no error is returned to the user/developer; also if the `el` variable is neither a node-reference or an `id`, [things go wrong: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VRnpc/5/)).

Having said that, I felt dirty, so I added in a simple error-check, and reporting, if the `el` doesn't resolve to an actual node in the document:

```
el = el.nodeType == 1 ? el : document.getElementById(el);
// if 'el' is null, and therefore has no value we report the error to the console
// and then quit
if (el === null) {
    console.log("You need to pass in either an 'id' or a node-reference, using 'document.getElementById(\"elemID\")' or 'document.getElementsByTagName(\"elemTag\")[0].");
    return false;
}
```

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType).
- [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
- [`typeof variable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with GWT's Label and HTML widgets!!!! @Andre Volgin answer is simple and correct!!!!!

Comment: @SSR: no, but it *does* meet the requirements of JavaScript; now: if an answer related to a tag is *incorrect* that tag should not really be there.