# Why doesn't setting the styles of Labels work?

Tags: css, gwt

I want to change the font size and weight in a label.  I did find this on Stack Overflow:
[StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090866/gwt-css-styling-part-of-a-label)

However it doesn't seem to fully answer the question OR there is something I am not getting.

Consider the following code:

```
package com.mycompany.project.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class StyleTest implements EntryPoint
{
    private final Label lblATestLabel = new Label( "A Test Label" );

    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
        lblATestLabel.setStyleName( "gwt-Label.TestStyle" );

        rootPanel.add( lblATestLabel, 204, 187 );
        lblATestLabel.setSize( "73px", "32px" );

        HTML hlabel = new HTML();
        hlabel.setStyleName("gwt-Label.TestStyle");
        hlabel.setHTML("Brown <span class=\"brown\">fox</span>");

        rootPanel.add(hlabel, 42, 36);
        hlabel.setSize("335px", "41px");
    }
}
```

And this style at the bottom of StyleTest.css:

```
.gwt-Label.TestStyle {
    color: Green;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

My expectation is that my text will be centered vertically and be green.  The result is no change at all.  I can set any styles I want and there is no change to either the Label or HTML label.  It all looks normal, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setStyleName` sets the `class` attribute (actually, the `className` property, but that's equivalent) of the widget's element; so `lblATestLabel.setStyleName("gwt-Label.TestStyle")` will be equivalent to having a `<div class="gwtLabel.TestStyle">` in HTML, that is an element with a single class of `gwt-Label.TestStyle` (`class=""` is whitespace-separated).

On the other hand, `.gwt-Label.TestStyle` as a selector in your CSS stylesheet will match any element with both the `gwt-label` and `TestStyle` classes; that would be an element such as `<div class="gwt-Label TestStyle">` (remember: `class=""` is whitespace-separated)

So, depending on what you need, either fix your selector (`.gwt-Label\.TestStyle`, might not work in all browsers), rename your class (e.g. `gwt-Label-TestStyle`) or **add** a class to the existing (for a `Label` widget) `gwt-Label` one (`lblATestLabel.addStyleName("TestStyle")`)